# DIsplay output of executable/script (periodicly updated) in toolbar or system tray

Tags: windows

I'm trying to replicate the behaviour of [XFCE GenMon plugin](https://docs.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-genmon-plugin/start) but in Windows.

Where I point a small program which has a toolbar/tray in Windows to another executable or a script, and get the output directly rendered in the toolbar. My only requirement is that this should have small or none resource footprint unless it's updating the output.